# NestJS-Prisma, How to write a DTO that matches the prisma one to many type

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma

I'm new to NestJS and Prisma. I'm trying to write an API for the corresponding prisma model.

Here is my prisma model:

```
    model orderable_test {
      id                 Int               @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
      test_name          String
      test_id            Int
      price              Int
      is_orderable       Boolean
      is_active          Boolean
      orderable_bundle   orderable_bundle? @relation(fields: [orderable_bundleId], references: [id])
      orderable_bundleId Int?
    }
    
    model orderable_bundle {
      id              Int              @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
      bundle_name     String
      bundle_id       Int
      price           Int
      is_orderable    Boolean
      is_active       Boolean
      orderable_tests orderable_test[]
    }
```

For the orderable_test, my DTO works well, the DTO for orderable_test is:

```
class OrderableTestDTO {

    @ApiProperty()
    test_name: string;
    @ApiProperty()
    test_id: number;
    @ApiProperty()
    price: number;
    @ApiProperty()
    is_orderable: boolean;
    @ApiProperty()
    is_active: boolean;
    @ApiPropertyOptional({default: null})
    orderable_bundleId:number|null;
}
```

For the orderable_bundle DTO, I have

```
class OrderableBundleDTO {
    @ApiProperty()
    bundle_name: string;
    @ApiProperty()
    bundle_id: number;
    @ApiProperty()
    price: number;
    @ApiProperty()
    is_orderable: boolean;
    @ApiProperty()
    is_active: boolean;
    @ApiPropertyOptional({type: () => OrderableTestDTO})
    orderable_tests: OrderableTestDTO | null
}
```

Based on the Prisma Official Document: I will need my DTO to be like

```
const createBundle = await prisma.bundle.create({
  data: {
    bundle_name: 'Bob',
    bundle_id: 1
    ............
    orderable_tests: {
      create: [
        {
          id: 'String',
          test_name: 'String',
          test_id: 1,
      price: 0
          .....
        },
      ],
    },
  },
})
```

But currently, my DTO will be look like this: missing the `create:`

```
const createBundle = await prisma.bundle.create({
  data: {
    bundle_name: 'Bob',
    bundle_id: 1
    ............
    orderable_tests: 
        {
          id: 'String',
          test_name: 'String',
          test_id: 1,
      price: 0
          .....
        },

    },
  },
})
```

And for the auto generated Prisma type: It looks like:

```
  export type orderable_bundleCreateInput = {
    bundle_name: string
    bundle_id: number
    price: number
    is_orderable: boolean
    is_active: boolean
    orderable_tests?: orderable_testCreateNestedManyWithoutOrderable_bundleInput
  }

  export type orderable_testCreateNestedManyWithoutOrderable_bundleInput = {
    create?: XOR<Enumerable<orderable_testCreateWithoutOrderable_bundleInput>, Enumerable<orderable_testUncheckedCreateWithoutOrderable_bundleInput>>
    connectOrCreate?: Enumerable<orderable_testCreateOrConnectWithoutOrderable_bundleInput>
    createMany?: orderable_testCreateManyOrderable_bundleInputEnvelope
    connect?: Enumerable<orderable_testWhereUniqueInput>
  }
```

I'm really new into type script and prisma, is it possible to have a DTO that looks exactly to the auto genenated prisma type, if not, how can I add the create: before my inner orderable_test under the orderable_bundle DTO. Thanks for viewing my question!

Comment: I think you copy-pasted the wrong information in some of the code snippets. Could you take a look (You posted both your schema and the create query twice). Your problem isn't super clear to me, could you try and clarify a bit better? Why can't you just use the auto-generated prisma types?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I just post my DTO (previously, I mistakenly post the model as the dto). My question is whether it's possible to create a DTO class just like those auto generated types which can automatically turn to create,connect,connectORCreate depends on the logic. I would like to use DTO other than those automatically generated types because in DTO, I can apply pipe, validator or guards to it which is more flexible.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply, I was a bit busy yesterday. I took a look at your solution. Here's a library that might also work: https://github.com/tpdewolf/prisma-nestjs-dto-generator if you don't want to generate the DTOs by hand. (I can't comment on how well maintained this will be moving forward though :/ )

Comment: @TasinIshmam Thanks for sharing this package. It seems very helpful. I was confused at the start because NestJS official website does not tell how to write a DTO that can fit the relational model well and I cant not find any article or documents about this part. Most of NestJS- Prisma tutorial articles are just simple relation or no relation models.

Comment: Happy to help 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured it out myself. I can adapt the similar format from the automatic generated prisma type to a DTO.

For example, I was trying to match a prisma type like this:

```
  export type orderable_bundleUncheckedCreateInput = {
    id?: number
    bundle_name: string
    bundle_id: number
    price: number
    is_orderable: boolean
    is_active: boolean
    order_infoId?: number | null
    orderable_tests?: orderable_testUncheckedCreateNestedManyWithoutOrderable_bundleInput
  }

  export type orderable_testUncheckedCreateNestedManyWithoutOrderable_bundleInput = {
    create?: XOR<Enumerable<orderable_testCreateWithoutOrderable_bundleInput>, Enumerable<orderable_testUncheckedCreateWithoutOrderable_bundleInput>>
    connectOrCreate?: Enumerable<orderable_testCreateOrConnectWithoutOrderable_bundleInput>
    createMany?: orderable_testCreateManyOrderable_bundleInputEnvelope
    connect?: Enumerable<orderable_testWhereUniqueInput>
  }

  export type orderable_testCreateWithoutOrderable_bundleInput = {
    test_name: string
    test_id: number
    price: number
    is_orderable: boolean
    is_active: boolean
  }
  .........
```

This type can let me choose to either create or connect to the other models I set relations with when creating this data.

For the DTO, I can write this one to match:

```
import {ApiExtraModels,ApiProperty} from '@nestjs/swagger'
import {CreateOrderInfoDto} from './create-orderInfo.dto'
import {ConnectOrderInfoDto} from './connect-orderInfo.dto'

export class CreateOrderableBundleOrderInfoRelationInputDto {
create?: CreateOrderInfoDto;
connect?: ConnectOrderInfoDto;
}

@ApiExtraModels(CreateOrderInfoDto,ConnectOrderInfoDto,CreateOrderableBundleOrderInfoRelationInputDto)
export class CreateOrderableBundleDto {
@ApiProperty()
bundle_name: string;
@ApiProperty()
bundle_id: number;
@ApiProperty()
price: number;
@ApiProperty()
is_orderable: boolean;
@ApiProperty()
is_active: boolean;
@ApiProperty()
order_info: CreateOrderableBundleOrderInfoRelationInputDto;
}

export class CreateOrderInfoDto {
sample_id: number;
sample_barcode: number;
}

  export class ConnectOrderInfoDto {
id?: number;
sample_id?: number;
sample_barcode?: number;
  }
```